# Get Firebug console output using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I want to use some values for my Selenium test. I can easily get this values via Firebug console[image]

I was trying to do it using **JavascriptExecutor**:

```
 public void getSomeValue() {
    String command = "screenX"
    Object jsResult = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(command);
    System.out.println(jsResult.toString());
 }
```

But I've got **java.lang.NullPointerException**.

Can anybody explain me - why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the "return" string before your command:

```
Object jsResult = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return" + command);
return (jsResult == null ? null : jsResult.toString());
```